# Disabling an <asp:TextBox /> in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I am working in an ASP.NET WebForms application built in VB.NET.

Depending on the role of the current logged in user I want to disable the TextBox. So If he/she is part of Role A, then he / she will be able to edit the content of the TextBox, otherwise the TextBox is disabled.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" 
             ID="txtResolution" 
             CssClass="newTextObject" 
             TextMode="MultiLine">
</asp:TextBox>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Make sure you do additional server-side checks. A disabled field can be circumvented to allow data entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `User.Identity.IsInRole()` method to check if the current logged in user is a member of the role you require.

The following code should work in the `PageLoad` method of the page.

```
If User.Identity.IsInRole("Role A") Then
    txtResolution.Enabled = False
End If
```

See [MSDN documentation of HttpContext.User Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx) for some more detail on the `HttpContext.User` property of web applications.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Role Management, you just enable the text box if the user is in Role A.

```
txtResolution.Enabled = User.IsInRole("A")
```

[MSDN IsInRole method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprincipal.isinrole.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the property

To disable:

```
txtResolution.Enabled = "false"
```

To enable:

```
txtResolution.Enabled = "true"
```